# Best VirtualBox settings for dev using Windows 8 and vs2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, virtualbox

What are the best settings (and the best way) to configure VirtualBox to run Windows 8 and vs2012 for WinRT development (store apps , etc)?

My machine specs are 64-bit Intel Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz with 8G RAM.

Any constructive advice is most welcome. Please be as detailed as you can.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Well if you're going to be working mainly on the VirtualBox VM then give it as much RAM as possible i.e. 6GB would leave your OS with enough to not cause harm. For VM hard drive the main thing that would affect performance is a Fixed disk vs a Dynamic disk. Fixed would give you better performance but requires setting a size limit whereas Dynamic expands as your data grows which takes more I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Have you developed using a virtual environment before? I have experience with desktop dev but never like this. Any obvious things to look for or anticipate?

Comment: Yes, both sandbox environments on local desktops and virtual machines on remote servers. They can be treated as the same essentially, you can configure FTP to transfer files between the VM or VirtualBox allows for File Shares that make it easy to move files between host/client. The main thing with most virtualization software is getting Guest OS Additions or Extensions installed as that is what allows the most communication between Host/Client and additional features such as copy/paste through the terminal. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for the info and the offer. I installed today Windows 8 and vs2012 in VirtualBox. It seems I was expecting more trouble that I'm actually finding. Performance is good enough so far. Time ot get my hands dirty. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A teammate of mine wrote a step-by-step guide on installing Windows 8 into Oracle VirtualBox running on Mac OS X: http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrisavis/archive/2013/01/27/installing-windows-8-into-oracle-virtualbox-running-on-mac-os-x.aspx

Comment: The provided article doesn't address the original question at all. It is simply a hand holding blog entry for installing Win8 into a VB guest.